# In Visual Studio 2015 is there a way to debug Javascript using a browser other than Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

The question is almost all in the title:
Today I was trying the new functionalities of VS2015.
I focused on debugging Javascript direclty from VS and I started to put some breakpoints in my angular code.

If I start debugging with Firefox (the same happen with Chrome) they become empty circles and if I move the mouse on the message is that the symbols are not loaded.
The only way I found debugging to work is using Internet Explorer.

Is there a way to bind Firefox (or Chrome) process to allow debugging?

Comment: Not sure why .NET Developers always want to debug in VS when the developer console is a lot better. Unless they changed something I did not read about, I bet it is still IE only.

Comment: Definitely not an objective truth, I find the developer console's step debugger to be terrible compared to VS, and maybe some people agree with me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if VS 2015 still has the browser link technology, but in theory that should allow you to debug for other browsers. See [Using Browser Link in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) for some hopefully helpful tips.

Comment: Thanks for the link... it's not what I was looking for but it can be a very interesting point to start to think a mechanism to integrate Js in all the browsers

Comment: Anyway I hope Microsoft arrives before all of us with a "something" that allows developer to do the job easily

Answer (score 2):

I know you can do it in Chrome so it should be possible in other browsers as well if they support remote debugging. Here is how you do it in Chrome. In the toolbar, click the button to get the dropdown of browsers to debug with and then click "Browse with...". Click "Add...", set Program to wherever Chrome is on your machine and set Arguments to `--remote-debugging-port=9222`. You can also set Incognito as I have to ignore cache but it is not required.

[image]

> Important! Chrome cannot be started before, Chrome needs to start fresh from Visual Studio otherwise debugging won't work.

After this goto "Debug" -> "Attach to Process..." -> select the chrome instance with the title of your project or similar and then click Attach.

[image]

If everything works you can now Debug your Javascript in Visual Studio and use all Chrome features as well.

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me in VS2015. Breakpoint never showed as being "loaded".

Comment: @jessewolfe Did you have an instanser of Chrome already started or did you let VS start it?

Comment: I believe I may have had other chromes running. I attached to the one that VS started, though. From your "warning" above it was not clear that no chromes should be started at all. I can try that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can debug js code using some browser specific addons . FOr chrome, you can take an eye at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: yes, I know there is the one you indicate correctly in your answer(there is firebug for firefox) but is there a way to integrate it in VS?

Answer (score -1):

You can try an apache Cordova project in visual studio 2015 and it should have chrome debugging as per https://youtu.be/Fr9qRNzBYZc